# How can I create a keras model from layers?

Tags: python, keras

This is a weird question. I've build some layers in a list called `input_layers`:

```
[<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x1377628d0>, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x138eb69b0>, <keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x13778dda0>, <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x1377f16d8>]
```

I want to build and compile a `keras` model from that. How would I do that?

I tried:

```
            new_model = Model(inputs=input_layers, outputs=output_layer)
```

But that gives an error:

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x1378fff60> (missing previous layer metadata).
```

Comment: What did you try? What was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the model is a sequential model (which seems to be the case) then you can simply use `Sequential` class to build a model from a list of layers:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential(layers_list)
```

Take a look at [Sequential model guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) in Keras documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the goal of doing that !

you could simply just add them directly to the model i.e.

```
inputs = Input(input_size)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

**Also don't forget the you've to specify the input size of the model,, so it doesn't make sense for what you're doing !**

Furthermore if the model is sequential you can do this

```
model = Sequential(your_list)
```